# Visibility of select tag

Tags: javascript, dom, select, visibility

I am trying to play with visibility of select tag,

Here is HTML Code;

```
<div id="dialog">
            <label id="">Hi</label><input type="text" id="input-name" />
            <select id="select-asd" class="selectpicker" name="Name" style="display:none;" hidden></select>
        </div>
```

I've already tried visibility and display properties, but I could not get any result.

Here is JavaScript Code;

```
var selectAsd = document.getElementById( 'select-asd' );
selectAsd.style.display = 'none';
```

Thanks in Advance

UPDATE** I think The problem is because of the "selectpicker"

Comment: can you do the following in chrome console.
document.getElementById( 'select-asd' )

What do you get returned ? 
Is it the element for which you want to set visibility?

Comment: What exactly do you mean here, do you still see the select after setting the style inline **and** with javascript ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yocine/1/edit?html,output — you've set display to none in inline style and it isn't displaying. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is not clear. But if the problem is that the SELECT is still visible, then probably the JS code is executed before the HTML is loaded completely. Try to execute the code after DOM is loaded.

Comment: The problem is that it is displaying

Comment: If it's still displaying with an inline style attached, the code isn't what you've shown us.

Comment: put your javascript code at the end of the body tag ? in order to ensure the html elements are created when you execute your js code

Comment: The problem is because of the "selectpicker" when I delete it, the select tag disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer;

Since the select tag's class is selectpicker, the following code should be used to hide/show elements;

$( "#select-asd" ).selectpicker( "hide" );

Comment: Probably you use Bootstrap or jQuery. If so, it would be great to mention that. People spend time trying to help you without knowing technical details. In this case you do not see a SELECT tag. You see a set of tags (DIV, etc) that are styled to look like SELECT element. Try to use "Inspect element" function of the browser to see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... If you want to make the select visible just uncomment the javascript 2nd line

```js
var selectAsd = document.getElementById( 'select-asd' );
selectAsd.style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<div id="dialog">
  <label id="">Hi</label>
  <input type="text" id="input-name" />
  <select id="select-asd" class="selectpicker" name="Name"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Try now.. the select is not visible any more

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your JS code into

```
window.onload = function() {
...
};
```